# RC5 : Lazy loading of NgModule in different router-outlet

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-router3

I'm using RC5's NgModule to do dynamic route loading.

My app has two depth level. I have routes like :

- app/login
- app/dashboard/module1
- app/dashboard/module2
- etc...

Each deph level has it's own router-outlet so I can define custom layout at each level. i.e. login and dashboard are displayed in app router-outlet while module1 and module2 are displayed in dashboard router-outlet.

What is the configuration to load dynamically each route on demand ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is a minimal working example of dynamic loading accoss NgModules and router-outlet.

**app.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [AppComponent],
    imports: [
        RouterModule,
        routing],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
    providers: [
        // some providers
    ]
})

export class AppModule { }
```

**app.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  template: '<router-outlet></router-outlet>'
})
export class BadAppComponent { }
```

The `<router-outlet>` where `/login` and `/dashboard` are going to be laid out.

**app.routes.ts**

```
export const routes: Routes = [
    {path: '', redirectTo: '/login', terminal: true},
    {path: 'login', component: LoginComponent},
    {path: 'dashboard', loadChildren: 'app/dashboard/dashboard.module#DashboardModule'}
];

export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(routes);
```

`loadChildren` point to the module to be loaded on demand.

**dashboard.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        DashboardComponent
    ],
    imports: [CommonModule, RouterModule, routing],
    exports: [DashboardComponent],
    providers: [
        // some providers
    ]
})
export class DashboardModule { }
```

**dashboard.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  template: '<div>sidebar left</div><router-outlet></router-outlet><div>sidebar right</div>',
})
export class DashboardComponent {
  constructor() {}
}
```

`<router-outlet>` where `/dashboard/accounts` and `/dashboard/transfert` are going to be laid-out. You should not name the router-outlet

**dashboard.routes.ts**

```
export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forChild([
    {path: '', component: DashboardComponent,
        children: [
            { path: 'accounts', loadChildren: 'app/dashboard/accounts/accounts.module#DashboardAccountsModule'},
            { path: 'virement', loadChildren: 'app/dashboard/transfert/transfert.module#DashboardTransfertModule'}
        ]
    }

]);
```

`children` ensures that children routes are loaded in current `<router-outlet>` i.e. dashboard's router-outler

**accounts.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AccountsFragment
    ],
    imports: [CommonModule, RouterModule, routing],
    exports: [AccountsFragment]
})
export class DashboardAccountsModule { }
```

**accounts.routing.ts**

```
export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forChild([
    { path: '', component: AccountsComponent}
]);
```

This is the end of the route. It will be displayed in the dashboard's router-outlet because is is a children route of dashboard.

**accounts.component.ts**

```
@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    template: '<div>Your accounts!!</div>'
})
export class AccountsComponents {
}
```

That is it. 
You should have all you need to structure your 'load as you go' application.
Hope it helps.

Comment: Could you please reference any blog/link, so that would be nice to further deep dive?

Comment: see [ngmodule official documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html) and [router official documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html) for more...